# how to fixed 'page not found' using django forms

Tags: python, django

Please help with the following error:
I get the error after posting the form

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/beam_diagram/
```

I want to redirect to another view after saving data using a form. everything works fine without the `test_id`

**views.py**

```
def new_beam(request, test_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("test1")
        beam_lengthform = beam_lengthForm(request.POST)
        if beam_lengthform.is_valid():
            beam_length = beam_lengthform.cleaned_data['beam_length']
            beam = beam_lengthform.save(commit=False)
            beam.beam_length = beam_length
            beam = beam_lengthform.save()

            return redirect('new_beam:beam_diagram', beam_id=91)
    else:
        beam_lengthform = beam_lengthForm()
        context = {
            'beam_lengthform': beam_lengthform,
        }
        return render(request, 'new_beam.html', context)
```

**urls.py**

```
app_name = 'new_beam'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<test_id>\d+)$', views.new_beam, name='new_beam'),
]
```

Comment: Do you have a URL like `url(r'^beam_diagram$', ..., ...),` ?

Comment: Hi Ralf, yes I do. urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('beam_diagram/', include('beam_diagram.urls')),
]

Comment: Does the URL for `/beam_diagram/` expect an argument? Could you add the URL to your question?

Comment: Your url conf does not have resolver for index page (without any id) which your are trying to open (`http://127.0.0.1:8000/beam_diagram/`) You've designed your  `beam_diagram` urls so they always are needing an id.

Answer (score 0):

your url regex is expecting digits not alphabet characters, pass a digit like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/10/` - which will be passed to `test_id` in view. Also end it with `/` in url definition like `...url(r'^(?P<test_id>\d+)/$`